# Ternary if php on affected rows in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Perhaps, this is dumb question. But I really to know use ternary if I have code like this :

```
public function add_tank_type($data) {
    $this->db->insert('tb_tank_type', $data);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

ANy solution is so appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need ternary? Just return the number of affected rows

Comment: I can't say if it's a dumb question, because I don't see any question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)  ? TRUE :  FALSE;
```

Comment: `? TRUE :  FALSE` is unnecessary since it already returns a Boolean.

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).